# Group a dataset based on values in one column against values in another

Tags: python

```
col 1    col 2
---------------
orange     a
banana     a 
grape      b
grape      a
orange     b
apple      b
orange     b
banana     a
```

I have two columns and i want to group them based on the value of `col 1` against `col 2`. I want the output to be:

```
   grape  orange  apple  banana
---------------------------------
a    1      1       0      2
b    1      2       1      0
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: do you use `pandas`  ?

Answer (score 1):

With `pandas` I can do:

First I create `DataFrame` with data from string but you can read it from file (`pd.read_csv`, etc.)

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''orange     a
banana     a 
grape      b
grape      a
orange     b
apple      b
orange     b
banana     a'''

rows = [row.split() for row in data.split('\n')]

print(rows)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])

print(df1)
```

result

```
[['orange', 'a'], ['banana', 'a'], ['grape', 'b'], ['grape', 'a'],
 ['orange', 'b'], ['apple', 'b'], ['orange', 'b'], ['banana', 'a']]

    col 1 col 2
0  orange     a
1  banana     a
2   grape     b
3   grape     a
4  orange     b
5   apple     b
6  orange     b
7  banana     a
```

Now I can group elements to count them

```
df2 = df.groupby(['col 1', 'col 2']).size().reset_index(name='counts')

print(df2)
```

result

```
    col 1 col 2  counts
0   apple     b       1
1  banana     a       2
2   grape     a       1
3   grape     b       1
4  orange     a       1
5  orange     b       2
```

And then I can use `pivot` to get expected result.

```
df3 = df2.pivot(index='col 2', columns='col 1', values='counts')

print(df3)
```

result

```
col 1  apple  banana  grape  orange
col 2                              
a        NaN     2.0    1.0     1.0
b        1.0     NaN    1.0     2.0
```

There are empty places (`NaN`) so I fill it with `0`

```
df4 = df3.fillnan(0)

print(df4)
```

result:

```
col 1  apple  banana  grape  orange
col 2                              
a        0.0     2.0    1.0     1.0
b        1.0     0.0    1.0     2.0
```